# ElseIf statements

Tags: vb.net

I want to ask how to do this based on a task i was given, i tried but it doesn't really work can anyone tell me why? Or even better if you could show me the correct version

The Task is:
Adapt the programme so the user must enter a quality for each diamond - Each diamond has a quality that is a whole number between 1 (low quality ) and 5 (high quality). 
Here is the code (Sorry if its bad i am new to VB)
Can anyone perhaps show me how to fix, i've been told the mistakes, but honestly i am not sure how to actually fix them. :(

```
Dim Weight As Integer
    Dim userValue As Boolean = True
    Dim diamonds As Integer = 0
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the weight of your diamond in grams")
    Weight = Console.ReadLine
    Dim Quality As Integer
    Dim DiamondPrice As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the quality of your diamond from 1 (low quality) to 5 (high quality)")
    Quality = Console.ReadLine
    If Quality = "1" Then
        DiamondPrice = "100"
    ElseIf Quality = "2" Then
        DiamondPrice = "150"
    ElseIf Quality = "3" Then
        DiamondPrice = "200"
    ElseIf Quality = "4" Then
        DiamondPrice = "250"
    ElseIf Quality = "5" Then
        DiamondPrice = "300"
    End If
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("This diamond costs : " & Quality * )
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to price another Y/N?")
    Console.ReadLine()
    While userValue
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the weight of the new diamond in grams")
        Weight = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("This diamond costs : " & Weight * 350)
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to price another Y/N?")
        userValue = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper().Trim() = "Y"
        diamonds += 1
    End While
    Console.WriteLine("The total number of diamonds entered is : {0}", diamonds)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Please please please put `Option Strict On` at the top of your file and read **[ask]** and take the **[tour]**.  You also need to fire up the debugger and step thru your code...it will answer nearly all your questions, in particular why it doesnt work.

Comment: It also doesnt look like you have done much towards the assignment (*enter a quality for each diamond*).

Comment: First after entering the quality you have to press enter twice, because of the `ReadLine` after the if else clause. Then you print the quality multiplied by anything. Then you ask if price another, but it doesnt matter what you enter, it will go forward since userValue is True and you dont change it. And finally you are not counting the first priced diamond :) I hope I saw all "mistakes".

Comment: Thank you so much R. Gomez this has helped me quite a lot and i got it working now :) Thank you so much